# How to get an Id out of a Url client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

If I have a URl like `"/api/User/Details/2c021192-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d"` what would be the best way to get the ID `"2c02ds92-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d"` out of the URL client side?

I need to be able to build a `$.getJSON` request with the ID and I'm looking for the cleanest way to do it using JavaScript, jQuery, etc. Thanks

```
$.getJSON('/api/User/2c021192-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d')...
```

Comment: This is pretty basic. Look up the `.split` function on strings.

Comment: is that a current url (as in, is it in the address bar at run time) or is it an url in the code somewhere or in a text field?

Comment: easiest way is to use `.lastIndexOf` or `indexOf  with string starting from -1` and then `url.substring(lastFwdSlashIndex + 1)`

Comment: there is a [plugin here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/e4Ank/) that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id is always going to be the last section of the URI, you could do something like

```
var url_array = document.location.split('/');
var id = url_array[url_array.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and extract the appropriate part (which seems to be UUID) from the URL.

The alternative is to just split the string by `/` and get last element.

**EDIT**: The example on how to retrieve UUID from the URI:

```
var url = '/api/User/2c021192-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d';

var pattern = /[\da-f]{8}\-[\da-f]{4}\-[\da-f]{4}\-[\da-f]{4}\-[\da-f]{12}/;
var match = url.match(pattern)[0];
```

`url.match(pattern)` returns array of matches, so assuming there is at least one, and only one match, you should pick it (using `[0]`, as in the example).

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/p6zud/2/

**EDIT 2**: Shortened the pattern used for matching (see revision history for comparison).

Comment: A very ungeneric regex example could be:

    "/api/User/Details/2c021192-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d".match(/^\/api\/User\/Details\/(.+)$/)[1]

Comment: @trueunlessfalse: It would be rather pointless, as you can do it without regular expressions. If you want to extract it only if it matches correct form, regardless of the position in the string, you can use `[0-9a-f]{8}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-[0-9a-f]{12}` (assuming the UUID will be presented as the one from the example: `2c021192-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d`).

Answer (score 0):

using `split`, convert the url to an array of parameters. Then last array item in your case would be your ID.

there are very sophisticated URL parsers out there for javascript, perhaps you should look around on google for one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alert("/api/User/Details/2c021192-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d".split('/').slice(-1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest:

```
var id = '/api/User/2c021192-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d'.split('/User/')[1];
```

Gives you `2c021192-25cb-43e1-9bba-3bd5604a0a3d`;